# VirtualBox How to move hard drive from one controller to another

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Virtual Box SAS storage controller allows faster IO than SATA one:

> SAS is to SCSI what SATA is to IDE: it allows for more reliable and faster connections.

from https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html

By default new VM is created with hard disk attached to SATA controller (at least for Windows VMs). In order to make IO operations faster in guest system, one might want to move a hard drive to SAS controller.
How to do that for Windows guest OS without breaking anything?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my own solution which seem to work.

Prepare (this is required to make Windows install drivers for new controller, without them Windows will fail to boot).

1. Add SAS controller.
2. Attach **new** hard drive to the new SAS controller.
3. Boot your system, wait while drivers are installed/updated. Reboot. Power Off.

Now we are ready to relocate existing hard drive:

1. Attach existing hard drive to SAS controller.
2. Detach it from old controller.
3. Make sure that `Solid-state drive` checkbox is in the same state as it was before.
4. Again: boot your system, wait while drivers are installed/updated. Reboot.

NB: Don't forget to backup your important files before trying this.

You might want to enable `Use Host IO Cache` on SAS controller.

Comment: Thanks, this allowed me to convert SATA to SCSI on Windows 7!